# Running steam on Debian 9 testing

Tags: debian, apt, steam

I am running 64-bit Debian testing. When I try to run steam I get the following error:

```
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed
Package libc6:i386 needs to be installed
```

I am however, unable to apt-get the desired mesa driver:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the i386 architecture first

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update
```

Then you should be able to install the desired packages